# Just one symbol that answered a question

Tags: mathematics, wordplay

I was doubting whether or not to go on vacation. So I asked someone if I should go.

The answer was given on a piece of paper, with only the following symbol:

∟

What did it mean?

---

Added hint:

> Which letters and numbers look alike?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They sent you

> a right angle or 90 degree angle

and the numbers

> 9 could be a lowercase g and 0 could be a lowercase o

so you should

> go

Comment: And with unit conversion, he could be saying "Go, and bring me back half a pie."

Answer (score 4):

Well, obviously these persons are in the US (no-one else would ever consider *not* going on a vacation), so the comment about

> the temperature being 90 degrees
>  (with the [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag in place, the '∟' symbol means "right angle")

isn't intended as "don't go, you'll boil".

Comment: I would interpret 90 degree Fahrenheit weather as a good reason to go on holidays, I certainly don't to be in the office. Nice reasoning otherwise.

Comment: Your thinking is in the right way, almost there! but a go or no-go can't be based on temperature ;) That's too subjective.

Comment: lbh unir gur evtug ahzoref, whfg arrq gb pbaireg gurz gb gur evtug yrggref :)

Answer (score 3):

You should go.

Vacations are great, and help avoid burnout, also this person is communicating cryptically...

> But they agree too, I think... either their depiction of a right angle is saying that it is only right that you go, or they're potentially using a Pigpen cipher to say C (sí) you should vamos.

Comment: Or maybe that you need to visit the rot13(frn)?

Comment: Really nice try, but it's not the answer I was looking for.